# How to match and trim a data.frame based on length of another?

Tags: r, dplyr

My experiment consists of measuring a dependent variable (Distance), during 10 drills (Trial), via two different measurement systems. There are multiple participants (Name). I am interested in how each system measures distance. However, the two systems have different sample rates and finishing times for each drill.

One `data.frame` named "Criterion" is structured as follows:

```
Source: local data frame [5 x 6]
Groups: Name, Trial [1]

       Trial   Name Sample Measure  Time    Distance
      (fctr) (fctr)  (int)  (fctr) (dbl)       (dbl)
1 D5_Sprint1   RUTH      1   CRITE 0.005          NA
2 D5_Sprint1   RUTH      2   CRITE 0.010 0.003429569
3 D5_Sprint1   RUTH      3   CRITE 0.015 0.003933275
4 D5_Sprint1   RUTH      4   CRITE 0.020 0.004403281
5 D5_Sprint1   RUTH      5   CRITE 0.025 0.004826486
```

The other, "Practical" is as follows:

```
Source: local data frame [5 x 6]
Groups: Name, Trial [1]

       Trial  Name Sample Measure     Distance  Time
       (chr) (chr)  (dbl)   (chr)        (dbl) (dbl)
1 D1_Sprint1  MARK      1    PRAC           NA  0.01
2 D1_Sprint1  MARK      2    PRAC 0.0012041589  0.02
3 D1_Sprint1  MARK      3    PRAC           NA  0.03
4 D1_Sprint1  MARK      4    PRAC 0.0009219522  0.04
5 D1_Sprint1  MARK      5    PRAC 0.0012165535  0.05
```

I am able to locate the end Time of each Trial, per Name, and the relevant row number using the code below:

```
PracticalDrillTimes <- Practical %>% 
  mutate(Row = seq_along(Time)) %>% 
  group_by(Name, Trial) %>% slice(n())

Source: local data frame [5 x 7]
Groups: Name, Trial [5]

       Trial  Name Sample Measure    Distance  Time   Row
       (chr) (chr)  (dbl)   (chr)       (dbl) (dbl) (int)
1 D1_Sprint1  RUTH    656    PRAC 0.015959010  6.56   656
2 D1_Sprint1  MARK    576    PRAC 0.014603082  5.76   576
3 D1_Sprint2  RUTH    651    PRAC 0.005423099  6.51   651
4 D1_Sprint2  MARK    746    PRAC 0.021403738  7.46   746
5 D1_Sprint5  RUTH    621    PRAC 0.032652871  6.21   621
```

I repeat the above for the Criterion dataset.

```
Source: local data frame [5 x 7]
Groups: Name, Trial [5]

       Trial   Name Sample Measure  Time     Distance   Row
      (fctr) (fctr)  (int)  (fctr) (dbl)        (dbl) (int)
1 D1_Sprint1   RUTH   1041   CRITE 5.205 0.0002099668  1041
2 D1_Sprint1   MARK    944   CRITE 4.720 0.0002195038   944
3 D1_Sprint2   RUTH    985   CRITE 4.925 0.0002437823   985
4 D1_Sprint2   MARK    977   CRITE 4.885 0.0002515801   977
5 D1_Sprint3   RUTH   1149   CRITE 5.745 0.0002597051  1149
```

I now wish to trim the Practical `data.frame`, to match the shorter drill length with that of the Criterion so that both drills are of the same length. For example, trimming the 6.56 second length drill of Ruth in the Practical to match the 5.205 length.

I have the Time for the end of each drill, but how can I effectively match and trim the Practical `data.frame` with the appropriate drill length?

I know I can use subset or deleting specific rows however, both `data.frame`s are > 100,000 rows in length so a quick solution would be ideal. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you wish to trim Practical by removing rows for which Time (Time_Practical, for clarity) is greater than max(Time_Criterion), for each Name x Trial. Instead of dealing with row numbers, one approach would be to summarize max(Time) for each Name x Trial combination, then join and filter as follows:

```
CriterionDrillTimes <- Criterion %>%
  group_by(Name, Trial) %>%
  summarize(MaxTimeCriterion = max(Time))

PracticalJoin <- Practical %>% 
  left_join(CriterionDrillTimes, by = c('Name', 'Trial')) %>% 
  filter(Time <= MaxTimeCriterion)
```